# How to add another Screen inside a Fragment?

Tags: java, android, layout, bottomnavigationview

I'm new to Android programming, and I have some questions about what type of layout to use. I am developing an application and have already done a basic mock-up of the interaction I want the user to have.

Following some tutorials I managed to build an app with a Bottom Navigation Bar with 3 Fragments, each one with it's own view. But my goals is that when the user clicks a button on one of these Fragments, the application opens a **new View on the same Fragment**.

What is the best way to achieve this goal? I have attached an image of the mock-up I made below, hope it helps to clarify the question. Thank you in advance for taking the time to help me!

[Link to the mock-up app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPeow.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's sounds like you want to start a new Activity.

Considering you have your fragments in CurrentActivity and you want to start InvokingActivity

On clicking button in CurrentActivity

```
onClickMethod(View v){
   Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, InvokingActivity.class)
   //put some extras if you like
   startActivity(intent)
}
```

To get arrow in top left corner you need to update AndroidMainfest by adding to InvokingActivity

```
 android:parentActivityName="CurrentActivity"
```

Comment: Thank you! I had some doubts whether or not to use other types of layouts but the Intent method works just fine.